# Auto select first available options from a variation on WooCommerce variable products

Tags: jquery, wordpress, woocommerce, taxonomy-terms, product-variations

I have a t-shirt product that has a choice of sizes and colours. After selecting of one variation I would like the first available option to be auto selected in the other variation.

For example, if I had a white t-shirt with only Large and Extra Large and a green t-shirt with only Small and Medium, when the user selects White it should auto select to Large. However, if the user then changes their mind and goes for Green, it should auto select to Small. Although, this should only occur if there isn't an already available option selected in the other variation.

Whilst I can run a script to select the first enabled option on change, once the user changes to a different colour again, WooCommerce gives an 'Out of stock' warning and clears their choices before I can run the script on change again.

I've attempted to run with on `woocommerce_variation_select_change`, `woocommerce_variation_has_changed` and `show_variation` `hide_variation` without any luck.

Any help would be much appreciated. Below is roughly what I've come up with so far:

```js
$(document).on( 'change', '.variations select', function( event ) {
        
    if ( !$(this).val() ) return false;
    var select = $(this);
    var variations = $(this).closest('.variations');
    
    $(variations).find('select').not(select).each(function() {

        var val = $(this).val();
            
        if ( !val || ( val && !$(this).find('option[value='+val+']:enabled') ) ) {

            $(this).find('option:enabled').each(function() {
                            
                if ( $(this).attr('value') ) {
                        
                    $(this).prop('selected', 'selected');
                    return false;
    
                }

            });
        
        } 

    });
    
});
```

Comment: Did you manage to get this working fully? I'd be interested in this as a PHP solution doesn't work for multiple variations

Answer (score 13):

You can achieve the solution to this problem using `functions.php` instead of writing js on the client-side.

```php
add_filter('woocommerce_dropdown_variation_attribute_options_args','fun_select_default_option',10,1);
function fun_select_default_option( $args)
{

    if(count($args['options']) > 0) //Check the count of available options in dropdown
        $args['selected'] = $args['options'][0];
    return $args;
}
```

note: The answer was copied from [Wordpress StackExchange](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/319604)

Comment: NOTE: If you want to select it only when there is 1 in the list do `count($args['options']) === 1`